# Counting rounds in a tournament

Tags: javascript, math, loops, formula

I've written a huge page in JavaScript for a tournament I'm hosting on a game. I've gotten everything I really need worked out into arrays, but I want to add rounds. The whole script adjusts to tournament settings (for more in the future) and I'd like this to adjust itself as well. So, let's say the tournament settings are [game,teamsize,entrylimit]. The entrylimit will be the key to finding the solution, because that decides the rounds. It works in a tree system (or however it's called). Let's say the entrylimit is 8. That means the first round will consist of 4 matches, and the second will consist of 2. If the entrylimit were 16, then the first round would consist of 8 matches, the second would consist of 4, and the third would consist of 2. I want to find a way to stick this into my loop where matches are written, and use the entrylimit and match number to generate the round number. All I need is a formula that can use those two variables to get my desired result. Also I apologize for the excessive amount of detail.

Comment: No need to apologize, the level of detail was perfectly appropriate. I'd rather you post a question with 5 paragraphs of text that just one sentence of "howz I make array like thiz in java?" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem, [here's an example](http://jsbin.com/inahu3/9/edit) of how the entrylimit can get the number of rounds and the number of matches in each round.

Calculations:

```
var entrylimit=16;
var amount_of_rounds = Math.log(entrylimit) / Math.log(2);
for(i=amount_of_rounds; i>0; i--)
{
  s = 'Round '+(amount_of_rounds-i+1)+' of '+amount_of_rounds+' consist of '+Math.pow(2, i-1)+' matches';
  alert(s);
}
```

​

Comment: Your code is partly correct. Your first round has 16 matches. An entry of 16 would imply 8 (1v1) matches in the first round. To correct your code, you only have to change to Math.pow(2,i-1). The last "round" should always be 1 match as it's the championship.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var entryInfo = [];

function populateEntryInfo(entryLimit)
{
    entryInfo = [];
    var i = entryLimit;
    while(i>1)
    {
        i = i/2;
        entryInfo.push(i);
    }
    entryInfo.push(i);
}
```